# Curve fitting a large data set

Tags: optimization, numpy, scipy, curve-fitting

Right now, I'm trying to fit a curve to a large set of data; there are two arrays, x and y, each with 352 elements. I've fit a polynomial to the data, which works fine:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
coeff=np.polyfit(x, y, 20)
coeff=np.polyfit(x, y, 20)
poly=np.poly1d(coeff)
```

But I need a more accurately optimized curve, so I've been trying to fit a curve with scipy. Here's the code that I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy import scipy.optimize as sp
coeff=np.polyfit(x, y, 20)
coeff=np.polyfit(x, y, 20)
poly=np.poly1d(coeff)
poly_y=poly(x)
def poly_func(x): return poly(x)
param=sp.curve_fit(poly_func, x, y)
```

But all it returns is this:

```
ValueError: Unable to determine number of fit parameters.
```

How can I get this to work? (Or how can I fit a curve to this data?)

Comment: Why do you think a _non-linear_ least squares method will give you more exact results to a _polynomial model_ (Which is linear)?  The linear result _is_ the best fit in a least squares sense. Using a non-linear method to obtain a least squares fit to a linear model will just take longer and isn't guaranteed to return a good fit... Beyond that, why are you fitting a 20th order polynomial?  Does that model make sense for your data? (If so, what the heck is your data, out of vague curosity?)

Comment: Are you wanting to do a spline interpolation, rather than fit a polynomial model to your data? (i.e. are you wanting something that exactly passes through each point but doesn't fit a single mathematical model, or are you wanting to find the parameters for a particular mathematical model that best reproduce your data?)

Comment: What is calling `numpy.polyfit` twice supposed to achieve?

Answer (score 3):

Your fit function does not make sense, it takes no parameter to fit.

Curve fit uses a non-linear optimizer, which needs a initial guess of the fitting parameters. 
If no guess is given, it tries to determine number of parameters via introspection, which fails for your function, and set them to one (something you almost never want.)